# I am trying to Load some Data from the API but UI is not Updating. The CircularProgressIndicator keeps Loading

Tags: flutter, api

**Here's where I am hitting the endpoints**
**I am using FlutterGetx**

```
static get_cryptos() async {
    final token = await SavedUserData.getUserToken();
    List allCryptosData;

    http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(base_url + "/api/v2/crypty/"),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      allCryptosData = json.decode(response.body)["results"];
    } else {
      allCryptosData = [];
    }
    return allCryptosData;
  }
```

**Here's what is in my GexController class**
**the GETCrypto is a Class and the get_cryptos is also a function inside the class GETCrypto **

```
 List allCryptos = [];

void getAllCryptos() async {
    allCryptos = await GETCrypto.get_cryptos();
    update();
  }
```

**And in My main class where I want to load the UI in ListView Builder**
**Using Get.put here**

```
List list = [];

  void getInitData() async {
    CryptudeProvider getxController = await Get.put(CryptudeProvider());
    setState(() {
      list = getxController.allCryptos!;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getInitData();
    super.initState();
  }


**ListView Builder**

child: list.isNotEmpty
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: 330,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, cryptoIndex) {
                            return InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.grey,
                              onTap: () => showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    SellCryptoDialog(
                                        cryptoCode: list[cryptoIndex]["code"]),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Image.asset(
                                        list[cryptoIndex]['icon'],
                                        height: 45,
                                      ),
                                      Text(list[cryptoIndex]['name'],
                                          style: AllStyle.text2),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        width: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                          //getxController.allCryptos
                                          list[cryptoIndex]['code'],
                                          style: AllStyle.text2),
                                      Expanded(child: Container()),
                                      Text(list[cryptoIndex]['rate'],
                                          style: AllStyle.text2),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const Divider(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    thickness: 0.2,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
```

> But it's only the CircularProgressIndicator that is loading.
> I think I am doing the right thing but the CircularProgressIndicator keeps Loading

Comment: Are you sure `list` is updated? can you please print it before setState?

Comment: It Printerd and Empty list like  [ ]

Comment: which means, `(await await Get.put(CryptudeProvider())).allCryptos!` does not give you any crypto. There can be many issues, so it's time for debugging. Firstly, I would check if the status code is 200.

Comment: Yes status code is 200

Comment: Then how about the response body? print out json.decode(response.body) and see if it has anything? Also, what does the update() function do?

Comment: i just printed it. Json.decode has all its data in it

Comment: We use update() method inside any method in the controller so that our widgets can listen to the changes made by the method. If you have used Provider package, it's just like notifyListeners().